# manage addEventListener() and removeEventListener() inside an object

Tags: javascript, oop, event-handling

I have a pseudo-class in javascript that has a method to add and remove listeners to two buttons.
This is the code:

```
function FirstObj(secondObj){
  this.loginButton = document.getElementById("login");
  this.logoutButton = document.getElementById("logout");
  this.secondObj = secondObj
}

FirstObj.prototype = {
  manageListeners : function(state){   //state is a boolean
    var self = this;
    if (state) {
      display += "none";
      this.loginButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
        self.seconfObj.makeSomething();
      }, false);
      this.logoutButton.removeEventListener("click", /*???*/ , false);
    }
    else {
      this.logoutButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
        self.logout();
      }, false);
      this.loginButton.removeEventListener("click", /*???*/ , false);
    }
  }, 
  logout : function(){
    //logout...
  }
}
```

the question is: how i could modify this code to manage event listener correctly?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you *can* remove an event listener for an anonymous function. Use named functions instead:

```
var myEventListener = function() {
    console.log("Hello World!");
};

myElement.addEventListener("click", myEventListener, false);
myElement.removeEventListener("click", myEventListener, false);
```

Here is a slightly modified version of your class that should manage the event listeners properly:

```
function FirstObj(secondObj){

    var self = this;

    this.loginButton = document.getElementById("login");
    this.logoutButton = document.getElementById("logout");
    this.secondObj = secondObj;

    this.loginButtonClicked = function(){
        self.secondObj.makeSomething();
    };

    this.logoutButtonClicked = function(){
        self.logout();
    };

}

FirstObj.prototype = {

    manageListeners : function(state){

        if (state) {
            display += "none";
            this.loginButton.addEventListener("click", this.loginButtonClicked, false);
            this.logoutButton.removeEventListener("click", this.logoutButtonClicked, false);
        }
        else {
            this.logoutButton.addEventListener("click", this.logoutButtonClicked, false);
            this.loginButton.removeEventListener("click", this.loginButtonClicked, false);
        }

    },

    logout : function(){
        // Log out...
    }

};
```

If you rewrite your class to take advantage of closures, though, you can simplify it to this:

```
function FirstObj(secondObj){

    var self = this;

    var loginButton = document.getElementById("login");
    var logoutButton = document.getElementById("logout");

    var loginButtonClicked = function(){
        secondObj.makeSomething();
    };

    var logoutButtonClicked = function(){
        self.logout();
    };

    this.manageListeners = function(state){

        if (state) {
            display += "none";
            loginButton.addEventListener("click", loginButtonClicked, false);
            logoutButton.removeEventListener("click", logoutButtonClicked, false);
        }
        else {
            logoutButton.addEventListener("click", logoutButtonClicked, false);
            loginButton.removeEventListener("click", loginButtonClicked, false);
        }

    };

    this.logout = function(){
        // Log out...
    };

}
```

Here I've assumed that `loginButton`, `logoutButton`, and `secondObj` don't need to be accessed from outside the class. If they do, just make them properties of `FirstObj` and update the code that references them (using `this` in scope and `self` out of scope).

Comment: yes i know this, but if i give a name to them, then i have the problem of "this" object, and anonymous functions become unnecessary

Comment: @Kucebe - That may be, but you still can't remove an anonymous listener, not unless you indiscriminately unbind all handlers for the event.  Named, whatever form, is your best bet.

Comment: @Kucebe: I believe you have the `this` problem whether the function is anonymous or not. I always simply declare a variable `_this` in the correct scope and use this to reference `this` whenever I'm in a function.

Comment: I can't give a name to those functions, the only way could be use global variables, but i don't want them because i'm doing it in OOP

Comment: @Steve: the problem is the function that the event listener calls is in another scope (logout() function and secondOBJ.makeSomnething() ), so i need anonym function to preserv "this".
If i use named function the problem of scope will transfer to it

Comment: @Kucebe: I've updated my answer to show how you could modify the code to use named functions instead of anonymous functions. I'm a bit confused as to why `this` is a problem, since you never use it (you use `self` instead).

Comment: @Steve:yes, your code is right, but there is a second problem: every time the managerListener func is called, loginButtonClicked and logoutButtonClicked are overwritten; so i suppose that the removeEventListener doesn't remove exactly the same handler.

Comment: In this way the listener is still there, loginButton fires event

Comment: @Kucebe: OK, I've modified the code to move the named functions into the constructor function so they will only be declared once. To do this, I've made them methods of `FirstObj`. Notice, though, that they're declared where they can access `self` (and they will always be able to access `self` because a closure is created); if they were declared  with all the other methods in `FirstObj.prototype = {...`, they wouldn't be able to access any local variables such as `self` and so we'd run into the `this` problem.

Comment: @Kucebe: If you don't want the named functions to be methods, you will have to rewrite the class so that it doesn't use `FirstObj.prototype = {...`.

Comment: @Kucebe: I've updated my answer to include a rewritten version of your class where the named functions aren't methods.

Comment: @Steve: Thanks Steve, your solution maybe is right but it doesn't work for my application, eventListener is always active, so i changed with DOM level 0 listener.