# removeEventListener, objects and this

Tags: javascript

So, it sounds like a trivial problem but somehow I'm not quite sure how to solve it.

Here is what I want to achieve :

```
function myObject() {
    //...
}

myObject.prototype.method1 = function() {
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", this.method3, false);
}

myObject.prototype.method2 = function() {
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.method3, false);
}

myObject.prototype.method3 = function(e) {
    //...
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work, because the scope of "this" is going to be wrong. My usual fix would be to use an anonymous function :

```
myObject.prototype.method1 = function() {
    var that = this;

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {that.method3(e);}, false);
}
```

But then I can't use removeEventListener

What is the best way to solve this kind of stuff ? I don't really want to use a global variable for an intermediary function.

Comment: _I can't use removeEventListener_ What do you mean here? It is working fine for me.

Comment: Take a look at this post and see if this kind of structure would work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170112/manage-addeventlistener-and-removeeventlistener-inside-an-object?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You could pass along the handler function to `method1` and `method2`. After all, it makes sense that those methods might want to register other handlers too…

(Changing the name of some functions to make them more meaningful here)

```
function myObject() {
    //...
}

myObject.prototype.listenMouse = function(handler) {
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", handler, false);
}

myObject.prototype.unlistenMouse = function(handler) {
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handler, false);
}

myObject.prototype.standardMouseHandler = function(e) {
    //...
}
```

Then:

```
var obj = new myObject();
obj.listenMouse(obj.standardMouseHandler);
// ...
obj.unlistenMouse(obj.standardMouseHandler);
```